# Конвертация изображений.

Tags: php, изображения

Нужно в php конвертировать изображения до определенного размера (ширина, высота), если они его превышают. Помогите.

Comment: кроп? ресайз? пропорционально?

Comment: Пропорционально рсайз сделать. Чтобы была уменьшенная точная копия. Например чтобы по ширине была не более 100, если превышает, то ресайз. Если не превышает то оригинал остается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
     *Делает превьюшку из полученной картинки
     *
     * @param string $img_to - если false возвращает image иначе записывает в файл по указанному пути
     * @param string/image $img_from - путь к файлу либо image
     * @param string $x_from, $y_from - координаты верхней левой точки вырезаемого прямоугольника из источника(по умолчанию 0)
     * @param string $w_from - ширина желаемой превьюшки (от источника), по умолчанию 160
     * @param string $h_from - высота желаемой превьюшки (от источника), если false приравнивается к ширине.
     * @param string $w_to, $h_to - высота и ширина превьюшки по умолчанию 160
     * 
     * @return image или path as string к новомой картинке
     */
function img_preview($img_to=false,$img_from,$x_from=0,$y_from=0,$w_from=160,$h_from=false,$w_to=160,$h_to = 160){
if(!$h_from){
    $h_from = $w_from;
}
if(gettype($img_from) != 'resource'){
$size=getimagesize($img_from);

if(getimagesize($img_from)===false){return false;}  
 $type = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/')+1));
  $get_img = "imagecreatefrom" . $type;
  if (!function_exists($get_img)){ return false;}
  $img_from = $get_img($img_from);
}
  $img = imagecreatetruecolor($w_to, $h_to);
  //загружаем источник
  imagecopyresized ($img, $img_from,0,0,$x_from,$y_from,$w_to,$h_to, $w_from, $h_from);
if($img_to){
 imagejpeg($img,$img_to);
return $img_to;
}
else{
    return $img;
}

}
```

я думаю вызывать функцию по условию про ширину будет не сложно.

Comment: @intranet, если этот ответ Вам помог, следует отметить его как верный, нажав на галочку.